# python if statement inside for syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I wrote some code but I can't get why the pyscripter is telling a syntax error in the if statement:

```
#search for 9 elements
file_writer = open('C:\\PythonProject2\\commands_NUM.txt','w')
for item in data_indices:
    flag= search_object(item,data,obj_value_min,obj_value_max)
        if flag = True:###ERROR
            file_writer.write('frame0: ' + str(item[0]+1)+' ' + str(item[1]+1) + '\n') ##Here is the syntax error

file_writer.close()

def search_object(pixel,frame,min_val,max_val):
    (obj_y,obj_x) = pixel
    y_center = pixel[0]+1
    x_center = pixel[1]+1
    if(obj_y<=597 and obj_x<=797 ):
        for y in range(0,3):
            for x in range(0,3):
                if((frame[obj_y+y][obj_x+x])<=min_val or(frame[obj_y+y]    [obj_x+x])>=max_val ):
                    return False

return True
```

Comment: `if` condition is not properly indented has only one `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` statement is indented inwards in `for` loop. And also `=` means assignment use `==` instead

```
for item in data_indices:
    flag= search_object(item,data,obj_value_min,obj_value_max)
    if flag == True:            #here indent this if one step back
          file_writer.write('frame0: ' + str(item[0]+1)+' ' + str(item[1]+1) + '\n') ##He
```

Answer (score 1):

there should be == in if statement

```
for item in data_indices:
    flag= search_object(item,data,obj_value_min,obj_value_max)
    if flag == True:
        file_writer.write('frame0: ' + str(item[0]+1)+' ' + str(item[1]+1) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Put your `search_object` function above - declare it before using it.
2) Fix `if flag = True:` to `if flag:`
3) Fix `file_writer.write('frame0: ' + str(item[0]+1)+' ' + str(item[1]+1) + '\n')` line indentation.
4) `return True` inside the function `search_object` is with wrong indentation too. Fix it.
I would recommend you to look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).